# difference between URL and path in Django?

Tags: python, django

I just started learning Django, and not able to understand that what is the actual difference between **URL** and **path** in Django.

Comment: Suggest you start with the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#path) which explains both of these in some detail. If you are still confused, then come back here with specific questions about what doesn't make sense to you.

Comment: The documentation confuses paths and URLs, no wonder there is confusion.  See my answer for an example of such confusion.

Comment: I don't think that changes the fact that this is a poor question - it's not even clear what the OP is asking. I initially assumed they were asking about `django.urls.url()` vs `django.urls.path()`, which might not be the case at all.

Comment: In the context of this question, the OP said they "just started learning Django". I take that to mean that _they are reading through the docs_, which I've shown to be a source of confusion which would lead to this question.  Giving an RTFM response isn't helping in this instance.

Comment: Perhaps the OP will clarify, but as the question currently stands there is no evidence that they have read the docs, or of which part of the docs they find confusing.

Comment: thanks, @Tyson and solarissmoke for helping. I'm sorry for not asking the question in the correct way that's because I'm just a starter in Django so it's also confusing for me. Well, I was asking about the URL and path that is used in URLs.py file by which we call the function in views.py file. Hope that now you will understand what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Until [Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#path) there was nothing called a `path` to define app urls. `Django 2.0` introduces `path` as a replacement for `URL`. Since you have just started with Django stick with 2.0 documentation and keep in mind that every forum you check will have solutions for older versions of Django

Comment: The `request.path` attribute [has existed since before Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path).  The docs have referred to paths and URLs all this time as well.

Comment: Yes, correct. the problem occurred when they changed `url` to `path` to define app urls. The confusion is because most of the forum still have solutions using `url()` than `path`.

Answer (score 5):

I know that this is an older question, but to answer the question directly:

- Since Django 2.0, the url() function is an alias to django.urls.re_path()
- And, it is listed as deprecated since Django 3.1.

So, you should use either path() or re_path() moving forward, depending on which meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP URLs are defined in section 3.3 of [RFC 1738](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1738):

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> `http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>`

Given a URL such as `https://www.djangoproject.com/download/`, the path is just `/download/`.

Sadly, Django often confuses paths and URLS.  For example, [all of the code examples for the `get_absolute_url()` method in the documentation return paths](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url), not URLs.

Some parts of Django do get it right though, such as `request.path` and `request.build_absolute_uri()` which use the correct terms.